# Prove that an Analytic Function is Conformal.

Tags: complex-analysis

EDIT: I am defining conformal at a point p to be such that the size and orientation of the angle between any two pair of curves passing through p is preserved under the transformation of the curves. And therefore a function is conformal in a set $U$ if it is conformal at every point in set $U$.

I am trying to prove the following proposition:

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be an open subset. Then a function $f: U \to \mathbb{C}$ is conformal if it is analytic on $U$ and $f'(z) \neq 0\, \forall z \in U$

Here is my proof, I have tried to mirror an explanation I found in a textbook:

[image]

I would like to prove this so as to prove that every Moebius Transformation is conformal. The main textbook I am using gives a geometric proof, but I would like to produce an analytic approach.

Is the proof given above sound?

Thanks

Comment: What degree of regularity do you assume for conformal maps? Real-differentiable? Smooth? Anything else?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I am not sure I follow, do I need to assume any regularities?

Comment: What is your question? You mention that you want to prove the proposition and you also mention its proof. What are you missing? Or is it that you want to particularize the proof that you have for the case of Moebius?

Comment: @owl Sorry, I should have made this more clear. I was hoping for someone to verify my proof.

Comment: Ah, sure. Yes, proof is correct.

Comment: Excellent, thank you :)

Comment: Suppose that your $f$ is not even continuous but $f$ preserves angles between curves. How are you planning to prove analyticity of $f$?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Ahh, I see what you mean. So the backwards implication certainly wouldn't be true without sufficient regularities on f. I think my proof shows the forward direction only which is all I need, so I will adjust the 'iff' to an 'if'. Thanks

Comment: Now it's all fine, except you should clarify the meaning of $Arg$ in your proof (there are different viewpoint on what's the domain of this function and even if it is a function at all!). By the way, if $f$ is continuously differentiable (as a function of two real variables) and conformal, then it is complex-analytic.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I see, I think our convention is to define Arg as the 'principal value' of the argument, i.e. $Arg(z) \in (-\pi, \pi]$. I am only realy using it as notation to denote the size and orientation of the angle.

Comment: That's fine, but for a complete proof you should still specify this.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I will make that adjustment, thanks :)